# Why is this small piece of code not working as desired? (JS for loop & 'this' keyword)

Tags: javascript, html

I made a very small fiddle to help myself on getting help here, I made the description in there too but I'll still describe this in here.. Thanks for your time, everything is appreciated!

Looks like I need to click the button and THEN, click the div as well 
to get the desire result, what I need is the following...

To click the button without the need of clicking the div as well too 
to load the '.innerHTML'

In the real code it is an ajax loading, and it only works if I click both, 
the button and the div. I want to keep it vanilla JS, I used to use jQuery here.

HTML:

---

```
<div class="divs">
  <!--- content loads here-->
</div>
<button class="button">Button 1</button>

<br>
<br>

<div class="divs">
  <!--- content loads here-->
</div>
<button class="button">Button 2</button>

<br>
<br>

<div class="divs">
  <!--- content loads here-->
</div>
<button class="button">Button 3</button>
```

JS

---

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', my_function, false);
}


// I want to run this function without the addEventListener.
function my_function() {
  var name_test = document.querySelectorAll('.divs');
  for (var i = 0; i < name_test.length; i++) {
    name_test[i].addEventListener("click", inner_function, false);

    function inner_function() {
      this.innerHTML = "surprise!";
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0zLkx2jo/

Comment: If you don't want to have to click the div elements, why did you code click handlers for them?

Comment: I took some codes here and there to achieve this and seems the only way is with the click handler, I just can't figure out how to make it work without it @nnnnnn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you don't want to have to click on the div elements, so *don't* add click event listeners to the div elements, do the update from the button click handler.

Within the button click handler, `this` will be a reference to the clicked button, and you can use DOM navigation properties/methods to get from that to the associated DIV - for your particular HTML structure the [`.previousElementSibling` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) is what you want:

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', my_function, false);
}

function my_function() {
  this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = "surprise!";
}
```

```html
<div class="divs"><!--- content loads here--></div>
<button class="button">Button 1</button>

<br><br>

<div class="divs"><!--- content loads here--></div>
<button class="button">Button 2</button>

<br><br>

<div class="divs"><!--- content loads here--></div>
<button class="button">Button 3</button>
```

Comment: Then you'd still need to use `this.previousElementSibling` to get to the relevant DIV, then use other DOM navigation methods to get down to the right `.p2` inside the DIV. There are a few options, including `this.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".p2").innerHTML = ...`: https://jsfiddle.net/yz8f9jav/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! now I can select where to load it.. I'll mark this as the right answer, my code is now working great, I'm not to deep into JS, sorry for the silly question. thanks a alot!!